# Custom Repository not working in Symfony

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I have created a custom repository but it doesn't seems to be working. i get this error:

> Entity 'com\twcl\agripayrollBundle\Entity\Payrollweek' has no field 'payrollweek'.

You can therefore not call `findByPayrollweek()` on the entity's repository. I know there's no payrollweek field but what would I change it to? When I tried the other fields I get an error also.

### Payrollweek Repository

```
namespace com\twcl\agripayrollBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class PayrollweekRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function findByPayrollweek($startDate, $endDate)
    {
        return $this->_em
            ->createQuery(
                'SELECT pw FROM comtwclagripayrollBundle:Payrollweek pw
                WHERE pw.startDate = :startDate or pw.endDate = :endDate'
            )
            ->setParameter('startDate', $startDate)
            ->setParameter('endDate', $endDate)
            ->getResult();
    }
}
```

### Controller - createAction

```
$payrollweek = $em->getRepository('comtwclagripayrollBundle:Payrollweek')
    ->findByPayrollweek([
        'startdate' => $form->get('startDate')->getData(),
        'enddate' => $form->get('endDate')->getData()
    ]);

    //If entity exists
    if ($payrollperiod) {
        $this->addFlash('error', 'Payroll Period exist.');

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('payrollperiod'));
    }
    //If PayrollWeek matches the Payrollperiod entered
    elseif ($payrollweek) { 
        $payrollweek->setPayrollperiodid($entity);
        $em->persist($entity);
        $em->flush();

        $this->addFlash('error', 'Payroll Period was added.');
        $this->addFlash('error', 'Payroll week was updated.');
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('payrollperiod'));
        //return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('payrollperiod_show', array('payrollperiodid' => $entity->getpayrollperiodid())));
    }
    else {
        $this->addFlash('error', 'Payroll Period was does not match a payroll week.');
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('payrollperiod'));  
    }
}
```

### Payrollweek Entity

```
<?php

namespace com\twcl\agripayrollBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Payrollweek
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="PayrollWeek", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="IDX_1B4F90669AD94696", columns={"payrollperiodid"})})
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="com\twcl\agripayrollBundle\Entity\PayrollweekRepository")
 */
class Payrollweek
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="startDate", type="datetime", nullable=false)
     */
    private $startdate;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="endDate", type="datetime", nullable=false)
     */
    private $enddate;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="normalHours", type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    private $normalhours;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="numOfDays", type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    private $numofdays;

    /**
     * @var Payrollperiod
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Payrollperiod", inversedBy="payrollweeks")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="payrollperiodid", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $payrollperiod;


    public function setPayrollperiod(Payrollperiod $payrollperiod) {
        $this->payrollperiod = $payrollperiod;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getPayrollperiod() {
        return $this->payrollperiod;
    }

    private $payrollperiodid;

    public function getId() {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getStartdate() {
        return $this->startdate;
    }

    public function getEnddate() {
        return $this->enddate;
    }

    public function getNormalhours() {
        return $this->normalhours;
    }

    public function getNumofdays() {
        return $this->numofdays;
    }

    public function getPayrollperiodid() {
        return $this->payrollperiodid;
    }

    public function setId($id) {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    public function setStartdate(\DateTime $startdate) {
        $this->startdate = $startdate;
    }

    public function setEnddate(\DateTime $enddate) {
        $this->enddate = $enddate;
    }

    public function setNormalhours($normalhours) {
        $this->normalhours = $normalhours;
    }

    public function setNumofdays($numofdays) {
        $this->numofdays = $numofdays;
    }

    public function setPayrollperiodid($payrollperiodid) {
        $this->payrollperiodid = $payrollperiodid;
    }
}
```

Comment: in the `createQuery` method, try `SELECT pw FROM comtwclagripayrollBundle:Payrollweek as pw
                WHERE pw.startDate = :startDate or pw.endDate = :endDate`

Comment: still get an error about missing argument 2

Comment: you are giving your custom query an array instead of just the two parameters `$payrollweek = $em->getRepository('comtwclagripayrollBundle:Payrollweek')
    ->findByPayrollweek($form->get('startDate')->getData(), $form->get('endDate')->getData()
    );`

Comment: I tried that also but when it reaches this line $payrollweek->setPayrollperiodid($entity);  it gives an error Call to a member function setPayrollperiodid() on array in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\AgriPayrollSystem\trunk\AgriPayrollSystem\src\com\twcl\agripa‌​yrollBundle\Controller\PayrollperiodController.php line 77

Comment: Your query also needs to be fixed to get one result instead of an array. Add something like `->setMaxResults(1)` after you bind your parameters.

Comment: Something is wrong at setPayrollperiodid. Not sure is what. Error:Attempted to call method "setPayrollperiodid" on class "Doctrine\ORM\Query" in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\AgriPayrollSystem\trunk\AgriPayrollSystem\src\com\twcl\agripayrollBundle\Controller\PayrollperiodController.php line 77.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150219/discussion-between-andrew-nolan-and-sue).

Comment: Good Day Andrew can I ask you a question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After speaking with Sue, this was due to mixing mapping annotation formats.  This is a common issue that a lot of people miss.  When people [generate their Doctrine entities](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/reverse_engineering.html) from the database and use annotations, they forget to remove the ***.orm.xml** mapping files in `AppBundle/Resources/config/doctrine`

The Symfony documentation states:

> If you want to use annotations, you must remove the XML (or YAML) files after running this command. This is necessary as it is not possible to mix mapping configuration formats

For more information you can look at the [Add Mapping Information](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html#doctrine-adding-mapping) section of the [Symfony Doctrine documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html).